# Eclipse IDE doesn't read keyboard presses until I click in the console

Tags: java, eclipse, keyevent

Right now I'm working on a project with JFrames and the sorts, but whenever I have something that needs to read keyboard clicks, it doesn't start to register them until after I clicked in the Console terminal within the Eclipse IDE. I'm not very well versed in Java and the Eclipse IDE so I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Key events are only generated for the component that has focus. You have a problem in your code since your component is not gaining focus automatically. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Usually it is better to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for a key event since you can handle the key even if the component doesn't have focus.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So when I run the file, it opens a JFrame. Although it doesn't register that I'm hitting the keyboard. Once I click in the Console terminal within the Eclipse IDE, the JFrame starts registering my keyboard. I was wondering if this is a setting issue or if my code just isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the method. It should open up the panel and then if I hit backspace it should go back to the previous panel.

```
public void scrapper(Cadet c) throws FontFormatException, IOException {
        frame.remove(panel);
        panel = new Scrapper(c);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        scroll.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(30);
        scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(30);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton back = new JButton("");
        back.setBounds(-1, -1, 0, 0);
        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("TEMP");
            }
        });
        back.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
                    home();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }

        });
        panel.add(back);
}
```

If you need more let me know.